# index.php not working with TOR nginx

Tags: php, nginx, debian, tor

all.
I'm using debian with nginx and php5-fpm. I had the site fully functional and then installed Tor to create and onion site. I was successful in configuring it to load an index.html however, when I use an index.php the Tor browser does not display the page. Instead, the Tor browser downloads the index.php. I'm not sure what configurations I need to make. The point of me doing this is for learning. I don't care about security or really using the .onion site. It's bothering me though not figuring it out. Thank you.

This is my server block config in /etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80;

root /var/www/html/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name 4bgxjb2vkb7tvsgw.onion;

location / {
 try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }

location ~ \.php$ {
 root /var/www/html/;
 include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
 fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
 fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
 }

location ~ /\.ht {
 deny all;
 }
}
```

snippets/fastcgi-php.conf:

```
# regex to split $uri to $fastcgi_script_name and $fastcgi_path
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

# Check that the PHP script exists before passing it
try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;

# Bypass the fact that try_files resets $fastcgi_path_info
# see: http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/321
set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;

fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi.conf;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What does `curl -v localhost` give you on the server?

Comment: `Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "59a030bc-137"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.3.0.2');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
        require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
        header('Location: install/index.php');
        exit;
}

// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');

* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact `

Comment: What is the content of `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf`? Add that to the question

Comment: If the existing PHP site is already working, why not just add the onion address to the server_name block?  `server { server_name domain.com onionaddr.onion; ... }`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 401 403 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
} 

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```